# How to use one module in another module in perl?

Tags: perl

Iam writing a perl script ,in which iam using a module **utils.pm** and in utils.pm iam using another module **DB.pm** in which i have a sub routine **connetToDB()**.

in utils.pm iam writing

```
use DB qw (connectToDB());
```

and below iam calling that subroutine as

```
my $connection=DB::connectToDB();         (This is line 30)
```

it is giving an error like follows. Can someone pls help?

**Undefined subroutine &DB::connectToDB called at utils.pm line 30.**

[you can see the DB.pm code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yy0BE.png)

Comment: You probably need to show us more of the code, particularly the contents of `DB.pm`. Does the `DB` package actually contain a `connectToDB` subroutine?

Comment: yes.it contains.. i will add the screenshot of DB.pm

Comment: Don't add a screenshot of your code; add it as code! And don't ever post database usernames and passwords in public places. BTW, you need to change your password immediately.

Comment: You probably should `use strict; use warnings;` at least

Comment: BTW. Your code is for `DB.pm` is missing `1;` at the end.

Comment: As an aside: Don't call your module "DB". That name is used by the Perl debugger: https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/lib/DB.pm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The direct error in the shown code is that inside `qw()` you need *names*. The [use pragma](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html)

> Imports some **semantics** into the current package from the named module

(my emphasis). The "connectToDB()", with parentheses, is not the correct *name* for the subroutine. The error message simply says that it didn't find such a sub.

So just drop the parens, `use DB qw(connectToDB);`.

---

The code for the package was added to the question and here are some comments.

A similar fix is needed with your `@EXPORT`: you need the subroutine *names* (lose `&`).

Perhaps more importantly, you defined the sub using [prototypes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes). Your sub is consistent with the prototype you use so I'll assume that it's done on purpose.

This is a very advanced (mis?)feature, which is very different from similar looking devices in other languages and is normally not needed. Chances are that you expect wrong things from prototypes. Go search for it. I'd advise against.

A side note: the prototype-related `()` and `&` are *not* a part of the subroutine name.

The last executed statement that returns in a module *must* return true, or code won't compile. The convention to ensure this is to put `1;` at the end of the package.

Finally, you shouldn't name the module `DB` as that namespace is used internally by Perl. Also, such a generic name is just not good for a module -- it makes it easy to run into conflicts.

Comment: i have changed module name  to some other . Now getting output. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Thanks a lot to [ikegami](http://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) for a number of comments and edits.

Answer (score 0):

use DB qw(connectToDB);

my `$connection=DB->connectToDB();`

or

if you have defined a constructor "new" in DB.pm module then

my `$connection=DB->new();`

my `$result = $connection->connectToDB();`